# Storing string value (consisting of integers) seperatated by space into byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a java program where I need to store the value of the string into a byte array (integer values are in string seperated by space). Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

ex:

Input:
    String str = "71 17 -93 -104";

Required Output:

```
// Byte array variable, byte[] myByte

myByte[0] = 71,

myByte[1] = 17,

myByte[2] = -93,

myByte[3] = -104
```

However I have stored the string value in integer array, but i am feeling difficulty in storing it in byte array.
Code that i have used to store String value in integer array:

```
       `String numbers = "71 17 -93 -104";
        String[] nums = numbers.split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i< nums.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(nums[i]); 
        }
        int StrArrLen = nums.length;
        int[] myArray = new int[StrArrLen];
        for(int i=0; i< StrArrLen; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]); 
        }
        System.out.println("\nResult:");
        for(int i=0; i< StrArrLen; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(myArray[i]); 
        }`
```

Regards

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just typecast the integer into byte like this. You have to make sure the integer is between -128 to 127.

```
String numbers = "71 17 -93 -104";
    String[] nums = numbers.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i< nums.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(nums[i]); 
    }
    int StrArrLen = nums.length;
    byte[] myArray = new byte[StrArrLen];
    for(int i=0; i< StrArrLen; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);

    }
    System.out.println("\nResult:");
    for(int i=0; i< StrArrLen; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]); 
    }
```